# Select contents of parenthesis in substring (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, string-parsing

I have a substring of text like so:

```
Serial Port Name (COM 1)
```

How would I go about getting the contents of the above parenthesis?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `comName = LikeSoText.Split("("c, ")"c)(1)`  you'd actually want to check the split to see if there is >0 elements, but you should get the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what regular expressions are ideal for, although this is a fairly basic match for them:

```
Dim str as String = "Serial Port Name (COM 1)"
Dim inbrackets as String = Regex.Match(str, "\((.*)\)").Groups(1).Value
```

This expression looks for parentheses - the `\(` and `\)` - with any number of characters in between - `.*` means match any character except new line zero or more times.  The inner part is also wrapped in parentheses to make it a *capturing group* - ie `(.*)`.  This means that the `.Groups` property can be used to retrieve the individual text from that capturing group.  The first group (ie `.Groups(0).Value`) would be the whole match, and would give you "(COM 1)".

Comment: Wow. This is awesome, and I think you just once and for all sold me on finally tackling regex. Great explanation. Thank you!

Comment: @Rachael If you do start off down that road, it's useful to have good tools.  My current favourite for regexs is http://regex101.com.  For example, [here is this one](https://regex101.com/r/yM3lE7/1).

Comment: Thank you so much, that reference really helps (It's always been overwhelming trying to find a good reference).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String.IndexOf` to find the index of each paren, then use `String.Substring` to pull out the parts you want.

You could also use `Regex` with an appropriate pattern to locate a match.